# Solving ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want solve the equations $(3y^2+x\cos{xy})\frac{dy}{dx}+3y+x\cos({xy})=0$, I used Integrating factor, but how do I find this? or Should I use another method?

Comment: Integrating Factor is: $e^{\int\frac{\frac{d M}{d y}-\frac{d N}{d x}}{N}dx}$, but, I can not express the term of the integral of x funcón. Also, I do not know if has a solution.

Comment: Check the writing of the ODE. There is probably a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it in the form of Mdx + Ndy=0 and then take the integrating factor  e^    \int g(z)dz where z=xy and g(z)=(dN/dx-dM/dy)/(Ny-Mx).
The solution will become an exact solution and then proceed.
(The differentiation are partial derivative with respect to variables).